# Different between several proposition - Manifold, plate function.

Tags: manifolds, smooth-manifolds

I have 3 different proposition and I really have problem to see in what they are that different.

Let $M$ a smooth manifold.

> **Prop 1 :** Let $U\subset M$ an open and $C\subset U$ a compact. Then, there is a $f\in\mathcal C^\infty (M)$ s.t. $f|_C\equiv 1$ and $supp(f)\subset U$.
>
> **Prop 2 :** Let $p\in M\backslash \partial M$. For all neighborhood $U_p$, there is $f\in\mathcal C^\infty (U)$ s.t. $f|_V\equiv 1$ where $V\subset U$ is a smaller neighborhood and $supp(f)\subset U$.
>
> **Prop 3 :** Let $K\subset M$ a compact and $W\subset M$ an open s.t. $W\supset K$. Then, there is a $f\in\mathcal C^\infty (M)$ s.t. $f|_K\equiv 1$ and $supp(f)\subset W$.

Excepted some very little details, theses 3 propositions looks exactly the same to me (and almost equivalent). What are the subtlety between them ?

Answer (score 0):

To me P1 and P3 are exactly the same. The difference is between P2 and P3.

P2) $f$ depend of $p$.

P3) You can take the same $f$ for all $p$ in $K$.